# opencv face detection is saving just 1 face from every picture, even if there are several faces

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

im using this code to crop the faces in my Data frame, the issue is that sometimes it is saving rectangles with no faces at all and i think other times it is rewriting the no face rectangle in the real face, it also save just 1 rectangle when there are several persons in the picture, i would like to save every rectangle as a pic even if it is a no face rectangle, i can manage that by hand by myself, the main part of the code is this(if is needed i can post the rest of the code)

```
required_size=(600,480)
names = [l for l in listdir(mypath) if os.path.isdir(join(mypath,l)) ]
for name in names:        
    onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(os.path.join(mypath,name)) ]
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(newpath,name))
    pixels = numpy.empty(len(onlyfiles), dtype=object)
    for n in range(0, len(onlyfiles)):        
        pixels[n] = imread( join(mypath+name ,onlyfiles[n]) )

    # load the pre-trained model
    classifier = CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    # perform face detection
    k=0
    for pixel in pixels:
        bboxes = classifier.detectMultiScale(pixel)
        # print bounding box for each detected face

        for box in bboxes:
            # extract
            x, y, width, height = box
            x2, y2 = x + width, y + height
            face = pixel[y:y2, x:x2]
            #resize pixel to the model size
            image = Image.fromarray(face)
            image = image.resize(required_size)
            face_array = asarray(image)
            # draw a rectangle over the pixels
        outfile = '%s/%s' % (newpath+name, onlyfiles[k])
        imwrite(outfile, face_array)
        k+=1
```

as i said i think the problem is that the rectangles is rewriting over itself instead of making a new one and save several rectangles, any help would be great, thank you all for reading

edit:

in the end this is the code that works, thank you all

```
#cropeo de caras y creacion de nueva carpeta para solo caras
required_size=(640,480)
names = [l for l in listdir(TOP_DATA) if os.path.isdir(join(TOP_DATA,l)) ]
for name in names:    
    onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(os.path.join(TOP_DATA,name)) ]
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(FACES,name))
    pixels = np.empty(len(onlyfiles), dtype=object)
    for n in range(0, len(onlyfiles)):        
        pixels[n] = imread( join(TOP_DATA+name ,onlyfiles[n]) )        
    # load the pre-trained model
    classifier = CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    # perform face detection
    k=0
    for pixel in pixels:
        bboxes = classifier.detectMultiScale(pixel)
        j=0
        # print bounding box for each detected face        
        for box in bboxes:
            # extract
            x, y, width, height = box
            x2, y2 = x + width, y + height
            face = pixel[y:y2, x:x2]
            #resize pixel to the model size
            image = Image.fromarray(face)
            image = image.resize(required_size)
            face_array = asarray(image)
            # draw a rectangle over the pixels
            outfile = '%s/%s_%s' % (FACES+name, onlyfiles[k],j)
            imwrite(outfile, face_array)
            j+=1
        k+=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to put

```
outfile = '%s/%s' % (newpath+name, onlyfiles[k])
imwrite(outfile, face_array)
```

inside the `for box in bboxes` loop so you can save an image for every face/box you iterate through.
It would be easier for me to understand if you can send me the full code.

Comment: tank u so much for awnsering, as i understand putting the outfile and imwrite on the for box in bboxes would write every face detected in the same file, do i need another loop for counting the number of faces?

Comment: you will have to make the filename unique for each face. You could just use a counter that increments within the loop